# Activating a Number of Hidden Inputs When Clicking a Number of Buttons

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a good number of buttons and a number of hidden fields...  I need to set their values using a number of buttons a la advanced search settings...

```
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value1">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value2">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value3">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value4">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value5">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value6">
<input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value7">

<ul>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value1" value="yes">Button 1</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value2" value="1">Button 2</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value3" value="indeed">Button 3</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value4" value="whoa">Button 4</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value5" value="34">Button 5</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value6" value="word_up">Button 6</button></li>
<li><button class="toggle" name="value7" value="no">Button 7</button></li>
</ul>
```

I know how I can go through and create some jquery/js for each of these to set the value, but I am wondering if there is a way I can just use the same jquery to set each one upon click?  Alternatively, these buttons will essentially be toggles, so I will need to turn them 'off' too?

So, to clarify, instead of having 7 individual jquery calls, can I just have one for all?  Would that mean a loop?  Is that even the ideal way of handling it?

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aptmuydn/2/)? the input type is changed so that we can see the assigned value

Comment: +1 for clean code @ArunPJohny

Comment: Thanks very much @ArunPJohny.  Could you please explain what is happening here: `return this.value.length ? '' : value;`?  I can follow everything else except that part. i.e. why 'length' and what does the colon do?

Comment: @CRAIG it is checking if there is already a value then set the value as empty else set the clicked buttons value.... for the toggle functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$('button.toggle').click(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('input.toggleinput[name="' + this.name + '"]').val(function () {
        return this.value.length ? '' : value;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aptmuydn/)